# Virtual networking, can ping and traceroute, can't apt-get update

Tags: routing, virtual-machines, network-attached-storage

I'm building a virtual network with 6 virtual machines in virtualBox.
One of them acts as router/nat/firewall.
This first machine uses 4 network cards:

```
eth0 -> Internet
eth1 -> Subnet 1
eth2 -> Subnet 2 
eth3 -> Host-Only Network
```

I got to the point where the machines in the subnets could connect to the internet by setting the nat in the "router" like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I started to set up a third subnet that comes out of another virtual machine in subnet 2 with these network cards:

```
eth0 -> Subnet 2
eth1 -> Subnet 3
```

Only one other machine connects to subnet 3, but I'm going to set up an ssh server on it so I need to route from the router to the machine in subnet 2 to this other one.
For that I used:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.46:22
```

In the "router" and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.30.50:22
```

In the ssh server machine.
Also, to get every machine to "see" each other I used:

```
route add default gw 192.168.20.46
route add -net 192.168.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.20.46
```

On the "router" machine.

Now every machine can ping everything from the other machines to 8.8.8.8 and traceroute them. However,

```
apt-get update
```

in any of the machines but the router send the package to the router and no answer comes back and so it gets stuck in the first line:

```
 0% Connecting ftp....(82.194.78.250)...
```

And never goes any further than that. (just errors when it times out)
My guess is the nat is sending the packages correctly but on the way back they can't reach the subnet machines.

Comment: This is probably not particularly helpful, but at this scale, why are you using Virtualbox, why not KVM or similar?

Comment: That's the software they taught me to use, if I use another one part of it may  be diferent. Risky, that's all. Interesting either way. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: Lot easier to back up VMs, and can run on one physical machine (power, heat, noise). The savings let you build up that central server with things like RAID10 SSDs that the whole "cluster" will benefit from in terms of reliability, speed, access times, etc.

At his scale though I would use docker containers, assuming the services running on each are compatible ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess was wrong. The machines were sending requests and the router redirected them to another subnet that either didn't know what to do with it or bounced it back to the router.
Solution being adding -i eth0 to the iptables line so that only external traffic is redirected.